# Change TextView to Int Value

Tags: android, integer, textview

What I want to do is change the text of a TextView to that of an integer, so that when displayed, the page will display the number.

At the moment, the TextView says "VALUEFROMfirstResult".  I want to change that to the integer  of firstResult e.g. if the integer produced is 23, the TextView will say 23 instead of the aforementioned.

```
public class Second extends Activity{

    TextView reslt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
    }

    public static void insert(int firstResult2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        reslt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or

```
reslt.setText(firstResult2 + "");
```

Comment: I think that this instruction will create in memory 3 strings, "", the rappresentation of firstResult2 as a string and the concatenation. So my solution it's a bit better because create in memory only 1 string

Comment: Worked like a charm!  It didn't allow non-static to be inserted into a static so I changed the "TextView reslt;" to "Static TextView reslt;"

Comment: Think so too StErMi, just wanted to add another option.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
reslt.setText( String.valueOf(firstResult2) );
```